# open CSV & replace all 'numbers greater than 100' in specific column

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to use python to open a .csv and edit the second column. Replacing any number in the second column, greater than 100 with another value.

Not sure where I'm going wrong, but the result is not as expected.

**INPUT.csv**

```
SKU,STOCK
12001,477
12002,18
12003,52
12004,197
12005,7
```

**Python Script**

```
import csv

with open('/INPUT.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('/OUTPUT.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))

    for cols in csv_input:
        for i in range(1,2):
            S = 100
            Replace_Stock = "100"
            cols[i] = [Replace_Stock if ele > S else ele for ele in 'csv_input']
        csv_output.writerow(cols)
```

**OUTPUT.csv**

```
SKU,STOCK
12001,"['100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100']"
12002,"['100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100']"
12003,"['100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100']"
12004,"['100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100']"
12005,"['100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100', '100']"
```

The output I'm trying to achieve. Replacing any stock values greater than 100 with 100.

```
SKU,STOCK
12001,100
12002,18
12003,52
12004,100
12005,7
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line `[Replace_Stock if ele > S else ele for ele in 'csv_input']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not opening the CSV files properly for Python 3 (see the `csv` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)). The results you're getting are because you're using a list comprehension to change a single element of each row (which itself is a list).

Here's what I would suggest. I've changed many variable names to better reflect the type of data they contain. The code also follows the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines to make it more readable. I suggest you read that document and start following its advice.

```
import csv

COL = 1  # Second column.
LIMIT = 100
REPLACEMENT = str(LIMIT)

with open('INPUT.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_input, \
     open('OUTPUT.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_writer.writerow(next(csv_reader))  # Copy header row.

    for row in csv_reader:
        row[COL] = REPLACEMENT if int(row[COL]) > LIMIT else row[COL]
        csv_writer.writerow(row)

print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
csv_file = pd.read_csv(link to file)
dict_obj = csv_file.to_dict('records')
for row in dict_obj:
    row['STOCK'] = 100 if row['STOCK'] > 100 else row['STOCK']
```

Then save the dict_obj.

Answer (score 0):

As avivd said, in pandas you can easily archive your desired output. It can be done even simpler:

```py
import pandas as pd

s = 100 # your limit
# reading your file
df = pd.read_csv("INPUT.csv") #  by convention we call it "df

# Overwrite for each entry in the column "STOCK" 100, if entry is greater 
# than "s"
df["STOCK"] = df["STOCK"].apply(lambda x: s if x > s else x) 
df.to_csv("OUTPUT.csv") # save your new csv file
```

I recommend having a look at the [apply function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for more information. It also has the advantage that it handles the datatypes automatically. Note that I could simply compare the numbers without any casting!

However if you want to have a solution without pandas, close to your approach, have a look at this:

```py
with open("input.csv", "r") as f_input, open("OUTPUT.csv", "w") as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))
    for row in csv_input: # note that we iterate over the rows
        s = 100 # your boundary
        # the column STOCK has the index 1
        # convert the number to int in order to get the numeric value
        row[1] = str(s) if int(row[1]) > s else row[1]
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```